# Accessing sub-tree that is stored in a variable causes exception

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm using Saxon HE 9.7.0 to transform some XSLT 2.0. In my file I'm trying to select a sub-tree and put it in a variable to use it later on.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<documents>
    <document>
        <code>009190</code>
        <index>3</index>
    </document>
    <document>
        <code>583876</code>
        <index>1</index>
    </document>
    <document>
        <code>277410</code>
        <index>2</index>
    </document>
</documents>
```

Now in my XSLT I select the document with the lowest index and want to use its code later (the variable `documents` contains the root tree):

```
<xsl:variable name="selectedDocument">
    <xsl:variable name="lowestDocumentIndex" select="min($documents/document/orderIndex)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$documents/documents[index=$lowestDocumentIndex]" />
</xsl:variable>

<!-- Now later on, I want to use the contents of the selected document: -->
<xsl:value-of select="$selectedDocument/code" />
```

This causes an exception in the parser which looks like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error evaluating template rule  at line 23 in module 
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.TemplateRule.applyLeavingTail(TemplateRule.java:366)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:456)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:2291)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1863)
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform(XsltTransformer.java:579)
    at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:185)
    at de.haba.genex.exp.core.model.nodes.XSLTTransformationNode.lambda$process$0(XSLTTransformationNode.java:146)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.saxon.value.UntypedAtomicValue cannot be cast to net.sf.saxon.om.NodeInfo
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.SimpleStepExpression.iterate(SimpleStepExpression.java:108)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.Atomizer.iterate(Atomizer.java:293)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.AtomicSequenceConverter.iterate(AtomicSequenceConverter.java:249)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.SystemFunctionCall.evaluateArguments(SystemFunctionCall.java:360)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.FunctionCall.iterate(FunctionCall.java:544)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression.evaluateItem(Expression.java:763)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression.evaluateAsString(Expression.java:859)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.SimpleNodeConstructor.processLeavingTail(SimpleNodeConstructor.java:186)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ValueOf.processLeavingTail(ValueOf.java:283)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:653)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:711)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:653)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:711)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:653)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:711)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:653)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.NamedTemplate.expand(NamedTemplate.java:257)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.CallTemplate.process(CallTemplate.java:356)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.process(LetExpression.java:568)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.processLeavingTail(ForEach.java:453)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:711)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Choose.processLeavingTail(Choose.java:835)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:149)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.process(LetExpression.java:568)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.processLeavingTail(ForEach.java:453)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:711)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:653)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.TemplateRule.applyLeavingTail(TemplateRule.java:353)
    ... 46 more
```

With XSLT 2.0 no more storing RTFs but keeping real temporary trees, shouldn't this work?

This is just a cut-down example of what I'm trying to do, I'm actually having a `<xsl:choose>` within my `<xsl:variable>` and the document structure is more complex, but the idea should be the same.

---

**EDIT:** It seems that my problem is related to that I pass the list of documents to another template first. Using the `xsl:copy-of` as written in the answers seems to work, but not when I do the following:

(Try it out on http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHL/2)

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="processDocuments">
            <xsl:with-param name="docs" select="documents" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="processDocuments">
        <xsl:param name="docs" />

        <xsl:variable name="selectedDocument">
            <xsl:variable name="lowestDocumentIndex" select="min(doc/document/index)" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="doc/document[index=$lowestDocumentIndex]" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="$selectedDocument/document/code" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Any more ideas of what's going wrong? I need to use a second template for this, because I use the template multiple times for various nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store a copy of nodes you need `<xsl:copy-of select="$documents/documents[index=$lowestDocumentIndex]" />` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="$documents/documents[index=$lowestDocumentIndex]" />`. `value-of` creates a text node with the string value(s) of the selected node(s).

Furthermore, some references/paths don't seem to matched, when fixing that I get

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="selectedDocument">
            <xsl:variable name="lowestDocumentIndex" select="min(documents/document/index)" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="documents/document[index=$lowestDocumentIndex]" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- Now later on, I want to use the contents of the selected document: -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$selectedDocument/document/code" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

outputting `583876` at http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHL.

There is really no need to create a temporary tree, you could simply select an original input element:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="lowestDocumentIndex" select="min(documents/document/index)" />
        <xsl:variable name="selectedDocument" select="documents/document[index=$lowestDocumentIndex]" />


        <!-- Now later on, I want to use the contents of the selected document: -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$selectedDocument/code" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHL/1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - your first example works, but it seems that my problem lies deeper. I added more detail to the question, do you maybe have an idea?

Comment: See the corrections in http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHL/3, if you have a parameter `docs` you need to reference it as `$docs` and not as `doc` (nor as `docs`).

Comment: Oh, right, like this it works in the example. I still have a different problem in my XSLT but I'll have to search some more.

Comment: Ah! I can see now what you were doing different to me. When using `copy-of` one has to use the entire path again when then selecting on the copied nodes. It does not copy the deepest selected node, but the entire tree that matches.

Comment: @maxdev, I am not sure your last assessment is correct, if you use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="docs"><xsl:copy-of select="documents/document[condition]"/></xsl:variable>` then the variable is a temporary tree with a root node containing a sequence of `document` elements matching the condition. Then, if you want to further select `foo` child elements of those `document` elements, you need `$docs/document/foo`.

Comment: If you want the variable to be a sequence of (unrooted) `document` elements you need to use `<xsl:variable name="docs" as="element()*"><xsl:copy-of select="documents/document[condition]"/></xsl:variable>` and then you can use `$docs/foo` to select the `foo` child elements.

Comment: That was my observation - if I'm mistaken feel free to correct!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<xsl:variable name="lowestDocumentIndex" select="min($documents/document/index)" />
<xsl:variable name="selectedDocument" select="$documents/document[index=$lowestDocumentIndex]" />
```

It seems that the `<xsl:value-of>` in your code extracted the **value** of a selected node (concatenated text nodes) not the node itself.

By the way: Your code contains `$documents/documents`.
Note that the last `s` should be removed.

Comment: This will not work when I need to use a `<xsl:choose>` within, as I wrote in my last sentence

Answer (score 0):

A stacktrace saying "Saxon internal error" means it's a Saxon bug. Possibly one we already know about and may have fixed, but a bug all the same. It's best to report Saxon bugs on the bug tracker at saxonica.plan.io. We will almost certainly need a "repro" - that is, a stylesheet and source document, and any other necessary details like configuration parameters, that enable us to reproduce the problem.

Just to give a little bit of preliminary analysis, the key failure is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.saxon.value.UntypedAtomicValue cannot be cast to net.sf.saxon.om.NodeInfo
at net.sf.saxon.expr.SimpleStepExpression.iterate(SimpleStepExpression.java:108)
```

That tells us that it's a run-time error and that we're evaluating a "simple step expression" which is something like $lhs/child::X where the LHS is an expression returning a singleton, and the RHS is an axis expression. I can tell from the line number that you aren't executing the latest maintenance release (because the cast to NodeInfo is now on line 110). The ClassCastException occurs because the LHS of the expression is expected to be a node, but is actually an atomic value, which means something has gone wrong in the type checking which should have caught this earlier. It could be an error in your code that we're failing to pick up and diagnose correctly.

Unfortunately a stack trace doesn't give us enough information to tell exactly what code in your stylesheet is executing at the point of failure. That's why we need the repro, so we can run it in a debugging environment and catch it at the point of failure.

That suggests two actions: (a) please try it on the latest Saxon maintenance release (currently 9.7.0.14, but watch this space), and (b) if it crashes again, submit a full repro at saxonica.plan.io. Thanks!